# UPDATE query with join on a sub table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table with traders  (TRADERS) and their supervisors. (supervisors are themselves Another table that have new supervisors (NEWSUPERVISORS) for the traders.

TRADERS - traderid, name supervisor, 
NEWSUPERVISORS - traderid, supervisor

I need to update the TRADERS table for the supervisor with new supervisors.

```
update traders set e.supervisor = n.supervisor from traders join 
(select traderid, supervisor from new_supervisor n) on e.traderid= n.traderid
```

This query does not work . Please can you advise what is wrong with this query.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? It's not possible to use a join in an `UPDATE` statement on many platforms. Also, when you say it does not work, in what way does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I am using postgresql. The error i get is column "e" of relation "traders" does not exist. I get the same error when I try @Pirate 's query as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Standard SQL:

```
update traders
   set supervisor = (
                     select n.supervisor
                       from new_supervisor n
                      where traders.traderid = n.traderid
                    )
 where exists (
               select *
                 from new_supervisor n
                where traders.traderid = n.traderid
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL queries simply aren't "updateable." You have to take an alternate approach, such as using a stored procedure which runs one query to get the `trader_id`s that need to be updated, then, perhaps in a `TRANSACTION`, loops over this result-set issuing individual `update` queries against each `trader_id` in turn.

Comment: SQL queries simply aren't updateable _by definition_.

Comment: Not necessarily so.  In Microsoft Access, you *can* create "updateable record-sets."  But only for certain types of queries. However, that's clearly an edge-case done for the convenience of that particular product and with its own SQL engine.

Comment: [View updating has long been a subject of interest in the relational world](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RXW4PtS4bEYC). But *querying* a database and *updating* a database are entirely different operations. Sure, the terms 'append query, 'update query' and 'delete query' are found in MS Access documentation but they are still oyxmorons! In my book, MS Access doesn't qualify as a SQL product because it isn't SQL-92 entry level compliant and therefore cannot be used in evidence :)